# jquery select live onchange

Tags: jquery

I'm adding a select box to a form by cloning the current table row, and then doing

```
currentRow.after(newRow);
```

Q: Using the `.live` method, how do I test to see when the new select option has changed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$('table select').live('change',function(){
    var select = $(this);
    var newVal = select.val();
});
```